# why do i get this error when installing gopls in vscode?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, gopls

when i try to install the necessary tools for the go extension in vscode gopls fails to install and i get this error:

```
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest FAILED
{
 "code": 1,
 "killed": false,
 "signal": null,
 "cmd": "C:\\Program Files\\Go\\bin\\go.exe install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest",
 "stdout": "",
 "stderr": "golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/hooks\n# golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/hooks\nC:\\Users\\DELL\\go\\pkg\\mod\\golang.org\\x\\tools\\gopls@v0.12.4\\internal\\hooks\\hooks.go:13:2: could not import mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 (EOF)\nC:\\Users\\DELL\\go\\pkg\\mod\\golang.org\\x\\tools\\gopls@v0.12.4\\internal\\hooks\\hooks.go:28:22: undefined: xurls\n"
}

1 tools failed to install.

gopls: failed to install gopls(golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest): Error: Command failed: C:\Program Files\Go\bin\go.exe install -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest
golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/hooks
# golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/hooks
C:\Users\DELL\go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tools\gopls@v0.12.4\internal\hooks\hooks.go:13:2: could not import mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 (EOF)
C:\Users\DELL\go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tools\gopls@v0.12.4\internal\hooks\hooks.go:28:22: undefined: xurls
```

i tried to install it from the terminal with:

`go clean -modcache`
`go install golang.org/x/tools/gopls@latest`

and i got this:

```
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools/gopls v0.12.4
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.11.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/tools v0.10.1-0.20230622221742-0622ad2359a7
go: downloading github.com/sergi/go-diff v1.1.0
go: downloading honnef.co/go/tools v0.4.2
go: downloading mvdan.cc/gofumpt v0.4.0
go: downloading mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 v2.4.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/mod v0.11.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/sync v0.3.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/text v0.10.0
go: downloading golang.org/x/exp/typeparams v0.0.0-20221212164502-fae10dda9338
go: downloading golang.org/x/sys v0.9.0
go: downloading github.com/google/go-cmp v0.5.9
go: downloading golang.org/x/vuln v0.0.0-20230110180137-6ad3e3d07815
go: downloading golang.org/x/exp v0.0.0-20220722155223-a9213eeb770e
go: downloading github.com/BurntSushi/toml v1.2.1
# golang.org/x/tools/gopls/internal/hooks
go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tools\gopls@v0.12.4\internal\hooks\hooks.go:13:2: could not import mvdan.cc/xurls/v2 (EOF)
go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tools\gopls@v0.12.4\internal\hooks\hooks.go:28:22: undefined: xurls
```

Comment: Works for me on macOS using Go v1.20.12. Are you perhaps using a much older version of Go? Or perhaps you have defined some Go related env vars that are causing a problem.

Comment: i use go v1.20.5 and i didn't define any go related env before